# How do I show values of 1 column horizontally - sql?

Tags: sql, confluence

I have a very small knowledge of sql, but I'm trying to create an sql table based on filter from Confluence macro.

I have 2 tables and I'm not sure how to write the sql to show what I need.

Table name = T1

```
| Key  | Title | Developer | Links               |
| ---- | ----- | --------- | ------------------- |
| RD-1 | Gray  | Jon Cruz  | PD-2, LD-4          |
| RD-2 | Blue  | Drew Lee  | PD-30, LD-12, PD-23 |
```

Table name = T2

```
| Key   | Assignee   | Links       |
| ----- | ---------- | ----------- |
| PD-30 | Kurt Penn  | RD-2        |
| PD-2  | Jury Souk  | RD-1, LD-4  |
| LD-4  | Grace Chen | RD-1, PD-2  |
| LD-12 | Gram Bron  | RD-2, PD-23 |
| PD-23 | Peter Tiu  | RD-2, LD-12 |
```

Resulting Table should be:

```
| Key  | Title | Developer | PD Assignee          | LD Assignee |
| ---- | ----- | --------- | -------------------- | ----------- |
| RD-1 | Gray  | Jon Cruz  | Jury Souk            | Grace Chen  |
| RD-2 | Blue  | Drew Lee  | Kurt Penn, Peter Tiu | Gram Bron   |
```

With what I tried, it's showing multiple rows of RD-1 and RD-2.
What I did then is to have separate tables for PD and LD and used multiple left joins (like below), but would like to limit the number of tables, so I would like to request your help please.

```
SELECT 
    T1.Key, T1.Title, T1.Developer, T2.'Assignee' PD Assignee, 
    T3.'Assignee' 'PD2 Assignee', T4.'Assignee' 'LD Assignee',
    
FROM 
    T1 LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.'Key' IN T2.'Links'
    LEFT JOIN T3 ON T1.'Key' IN T3.'Links'
    LEFT JOIN T4 ON T1.'Key' IN T4.'Links';
```

Thank you!

Comment: "but would like to limit the number of tables"  Why?

Comment: I am using "Filter Results" macro in Confluence to generate the table then Table Transformer for the sql, and it seems buggy with more than 2 filters + it might cause more difficulty to manage the filter when passed down to others.

Comment: Normalize you database design at least to 3NF. As it is it doesn't reach 1NF.

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3). Goes for table names as well, even if it's just for the purpose of this question

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like joins you can try someting like this ). So, you can mark this as answer if it's it.

```
SELECT 
    T1.[Key]
    ,T1.[Title]
    ,T1.[Developer]
    ,[PD Assignee]= (
                     SELECT stuff
                           (
                                  (
                                   SELECT ','+ T2.[Assignee] 
                                   FROM T2  
                                   WHERE T2.[Links] LIKE ('%' + T1.[Key] + '%') AND T2.[Key] LIKE '%PD%' 
                                   FOR xml PATH('')
                                   )
                                   , 1, 1, ''
                           )
                    )
    ,[LD Assignee]= (
                     SELECT stuff
                           (
                                  (
                                   SELECT ','+ T2.[Assignee] 
                                   FROM T2  
                                   WHERE T2.[Links] LIKE ('%' + T1.[Key] + '%') AND T2.[Key] LIKE '%LD%' 
                                   FOR xml PATH('')
                                   )
                                   , 1, 1, ''
                           )
                    )
FROM T1
```

Comment: How does this answer deal with a database that is [supported by confluence](https://confluence.atlassian.com/confeap/supported-platforms-1044798593.html), but does not support [STUFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) ?

Comment: Thats is why you have 9k+ reputation ). You are right it will be a problem. Frankly speaking I didn't think about it. From the other side it's just non-obligatory supportive function. I see the value of the answer in an approach.